# How can i check availability of a product using pincode feature?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, pincodes

How can i check availability of a product using pin-code in checkout page in magento ?

Is it can be override the core functionality or have to include a custom module ?

Comment: yes, you can use http://www.nextbits.eu/check-delivery-availability-magento-extension.html
this extension. it will surely help you. i have used it.

Comment: How did you use it ? via magento connect or manual folder upload ?

Comment: manual folder upload. download extension and upload files.

Comment: ok let me try thks

Comment: I uploaded the files to specific folders , but no efect

Comment: it will shows functionality on product view page. if you uploaded files in correct theme folder.

Comment: if you want to use it. on checkout page you need little customization.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21398/discussion-between-icecreamsandwich-and-punit).

Comment: How to do that , pls help me

Comment: Yea now its okay @punit, its visible , but positioning is not correct in checkout page

Comment: it's not displaying in frontend for me....

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich did you got skin and js folders for this extension? i got only app folder.... [http://www.nextbits.eu/check-delivery-availability-magento-extension.html]

Comment: @punit  did you got skin and js folders for this extension? i got only app folder.... [http://www.nextbits.eu/check-delivery-availability-magento-extension.html]

Comment: i am follwing manualy installing extension. is we have to follow different procedure to install this extension?

Answer (score 3):

Icecreamsandwich,magento donot have this feature in default.You need to customize or need to use extension.

**Paid extension like**

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/logistics-features-availability-estimator-by-pincode.html

**Free:**

http://www.nextbits.eu/check-delivery-availability-magento-extension.html

Comment: okay , let me look on this

Comment: I copied the files to exact locations ,  in admin panel ->System->configurations->Check delivery it gives me a 404 not found error

Comment: It magento admin user permission issue.Just goto system>Permission>roles Select your admin role then click on save button.Logout and login again.It may be works

Comment: ok let me try tks

Comment: Its already administrator there

Comment: No , its available to configure in admin panel , but the block is not appear in front end

Comment: @amit  did you got skin and js folders for this extension? i got only app folder.... [http://www.nextbits.eu/check-delivery-availability-magento-extension.html]

Comment: Iam also not received all flders. I got only app folder?